# Java: Binary Tree Node displaying only memory addresses or null

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have a node class and am just trying to narrow down an issue when adding elements to my tree. I think my node class is just not properly creating the node to add in the tree. When I print each node, it is returning memory addresses, I believe. I cannot seem to get it to print anything else. Any help in determining if my node class is faulty would be great.

Example of what my program prints:

```
([C@f72003d)
([C@56dacb7)
([C@63662529)
([C@4711d9ba)
```

The `TreeNode` class:

```
public class TreeNode {

char[] data;
TreeNode left, right, parent;
// used for printing:
int column;
int row;
int center;


public TreeNode(char[] data) {
    this.data = data;
    left = right = parent = null;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "(" + data + ")";
}
public int return_letter(){
    char x = data[0];
    int b = Character.getNumericValue(x);
    return b;        
}

public int findMaxDepth() {
    int lmax = 0;
    int rmax = 0;
    if (left != null) {
        lmax = left.findMaxDepth();
    }
    if (right != null) {
        rmax = right.findMaxDepth();
    }
    return 1 + Math.max(lmax, rmax);
}

}
```

Comment: You haven't really described your issue... please provide us with more information. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would be helpful.

Comment: could you please post whatever error message you are getting?

Comment: `@Override
public String toString() {return "(" + data + ")";}` will not print what you want. Use `Arrays.toString(data)` to get a String representation of the content of your array.

Comment: Thanks ZouZou, that was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String toString() {
    return "(" + data + ")";
}
```

You're problem is here. `toString()` is returning the memory references of `data` and its contained elements. You can either use `Arrays.toString(data)` inside this method to get a string representation of the items in the array, or in your method that is printing out the data, do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    println(data[i]);
}
```